# What does the phrase "do your bit for your fellow gentlemen" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

Does *gentlemen* in the phrase *"do your bit for your fellow gentlemen"* mean yourself, or fellows at your company, or someone else?

Comment: It is totally context-dependent.

Comment: @medica One of the OP's queries is whether *gentlemen* here is a vocative within the phrase *fellow gentlemen*. In this case, unless I'm gravely mistaken -which is of course possible - it is definitely not! I don't really see how it could be here regardless of the context ...

Comment: @Araucaria - I am not at all sure what he is asking. But it sounds like which persons *fellow gentlemen* refers to is dependent on context to me. :)

Comment: @medica EDIT: He's asking whether *gentlemen* is used in such phrases as a vocative when he asks about *yourself*. Eg does it mean *Gentlemen, do your bit for your fellow!* Or for example *Do your bit for your fellow, Medica!*

Comment: @Araucaria - wouldn't there be a comma there if it were the vocative? Or, better yet, Gentlemen, do... In any case, it's closed as unclear, which, I think, is appropriate.

Comment: @medica imo, there should be, but it's not a requirement I don't think ... :)

Answer (score 0):

As Medica says, it's totally context dependent. It's probably not for yourself, more likely for the group of people that whoever said it believes you are a part of.

Typically it would be said by a boss, leader or member of a group, to remind you that you need to contribute more, or perform some act that benefits the group.